# Regex for Non-negative numbers with two decimals OR Non-negative Integers. No leading 0

Tags: regex, validation

As-salāmu ʿalaykum,

```
Allowed:

0
0.00
0.01
0.10
0.11
1
1.00
1.10
1.01
1.11
99999999
99999999.00
99999999.01
99999999.10
99999999.11

NOT ALLOWED:
.
.00
00
00.
00.00
00.01
00.10
00.11
01
010
01.
01.00
01.000
```

I could go on but i think you get the gist of what I want. The Regex will be used to validate currency, with a maximum of two optional decimals. No upper limit for the left hand side of the decimal, as long as it isn't a leading 0.

It will be used in a Java-application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the problem with this question is that there is no questionmark at the end? Don't you have anything better to do?

Answer (score 1):

One option is, from the start of the string, use negative lookahead for 0 followed by a digit, and then just test for digits optionally followed by a `.` which is followed by more digits:

```
^(?!0\d)\d+(\.\d\d)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/5nUmlI/1/